# Is this an array with foreach?

Tags: php

I have three variables ($var, $var2 & $var3) and I want it to output when they have value.

For example, if `$var = "Data";` then:

```
<ul>
<li>Data</li>
</ul>
```

And if any of the other variables has value then:

```
<ul>
<li>Data</li>
<li>Data2</li>
</ul>
```

Or

```
<ul>
<li>Data</li>
<li>Data3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>Data</li>
<li>Data3</li>
<li>Data2</li>
</ul>
```

I am not exactly sure how to create this and with what method considering everybody has different ways of doing their php code. Does anybody know how I can create this?

Also: I use http://writecodeonline.com/php/ when testing certain php codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach (array($var1, $var2, $var3) as $var) : ?>
        <?php if (!empty($var)) : ?>
            <li><?php echo $var; ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

You can [see the output here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) on `writecodeonline.com`.

---

Or maybe you prefer this:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach (array($var1, $var2, $var3) as $var) {
        if (!empty($var)) {
            echo '<li>' . $var . '</li>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

(it doesn't matter really, just use whatever you think looks better)

Comment: did you really need to start stop the php parsing on every line?

Comment: If you don't use a template engine, this is (in my opinion, and I believe I share it with many PHP developers) the cleanest way to do it. Also, you don't start/stop the PHP engine every time you open/close the `php` tags...

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! Especially when it is empty, I won't see a dot with nothing next to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach(array($var, $var2, $var3) as $value) : ?>
    <?php if (!empty($value)) : ?>
        <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Our answers are too damn similar! :D

Comment: deleted my answer -- couldn't figure out how to get the php tags to show up on here :)   +1, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array, and foreach to print the variables.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

or you can use this (what I not recommend):

```
if(isset($var)) {
    echo $var;
}
if(isset($var1)) {
    echo $var1;
}
if(isset($var2)) {
    echo $var2;
}
```

Best is var-args in my opinion.

```
function funcName() {
    for ($i = 0;$i < func_num_args();$i++) {
        echo '<li>'.func_get_arg($i).'</li>';
}
echo funcName($var,$var1,$var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose from the title that your variables are inside an array.

If so, just do a foreach loop

```
foreach($arrayVars as $var)
{
  if(isset($var))
  {
   echo '<li>'.$var.'</li>
  }
}
```

Anyway, you should explain clearly what your problem is. I making assumptions here because your not very explicit on what your problem is.